# Display DICOM and binary data

Tags: javascript, html, dicom

I need to know if it is possible to do the following using javascript and HTML5:

- Open a DICOM file and display it
- Draw an image using binary data

Any suggestions? Sample code or a tutorial will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a great library for that (there are code samples and visualization examples on its page): https://github.com/xtk/X#readme

With a `.dicom` files you would probably need to have a single file, not some series in folders. But even if you have sequence of files, you could convert them to some other format that would suite this library (`.nrrd` or something else).

Answer (score 0):

It's completely "do-able" as HTML5 supports file reading capabilities.  In addition to that, you can manipulate bits and bytes so you can easily read the tags.  I have done something similar, only that, in my case, i only process the dicom image, processing in full bit-depth (16bit) of course : )